# Por que essa interpolação de string gera erro

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código PHP :

```
<?php

class Animal
{
  private $nome;
  public function getNome():string
  {
    return $this->nome;
  }
  public function setNome($value)
  {
    $this->nome=$value;
  }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal
{
  public function Andar()
  {
    echo $this->getNome() ." está andando."; //Essa linha funciona
    echo "$this->getNome() está andando."; //Essa linha gera o erro: Notice: Undefined property: Dog::$getName in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackoverflow\question1\sample.php on line 27 () is walking.
  }
}

$cao = new Cachorro();
$cao->setNome("Snoopy");
$cao->Andar();

 ?>
```

Por que dá erro quando faço?

```
echo $this->getNome() ." está andando."; //Essa linha funciona
echo "$this->getNome() está andando."; //Essa linha gera o erro: Notice: Undefined property: Dog::$getName in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackoverflow\question1\sample.php on line 27 () is walking.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque função não roda dentro de string (dentro das aspas) da forma que você utilizou:

```
echo "$this->getNome() está andando.";
```

Então é como se a `string` pensasse que os parenteses não fizessem parte do método e pensa que você esta tentando pegar uma propriedade com o nome `getNome`, mas como não existe tal propriedade com este nome e sim um método então causa o erro.

Resumindo, dentro das aspas os parenteses não são reconhecido como parte do que você tentou chamar, mas sim como parte da `string` apenas.

Já no primeiro exemplo esta fora da `string` e concatenando com ela, ou seja o parser do interpretador de PHP reconhece como um método:

```
echo $this->getNome() ." está andando.";
```

No entanto note que para usar dentro de aspas você pode usar as [**chaves `{}`**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_(pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), o que vai tornar até mais intuitivo o seu código, veja que desta forma funciona:

```
echo "{$this->getNome()} está andando.";
```

Exemplo:

```
class Cachorro extends Animal
{
    public function Andar()
    {
        echo "{$this->getNome()} está andando.";
    }
}
```

Leia mais sobre as chaves em [**Complex (curly) syntax**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)